Automation Account Script to delete Stale Devices
I am trying to create a runbook in my Automation Account which deletes all stale devices (inactive for >= 180 days) from Entra.
I have an App Registration with the correct API permissions already created and uploaded the certificate to my Automation Account, I installed the needed modules as well.
API Permissions:

I am still running into some problems though, the current version of the script just displays the welcome to graph message and then apparently quits the script, even though I added lots of debugging steps:
Welcome to Microsoft Graph!

Connected via apponly access using 12345567-1213-2333-xxxxxxxx

Readme: https://aka.ms/graph/sdk/powershell

SDK Docs: https://aka.ms/graph/sdk/powershell/docs

API Docs: https://aka.ms/graph/docs

NOTE: You can use the -NoWelcome parameter to suppress this message.


The script goes like this:
# Set the tenant ID and App Registration details
$tenantId = "tenantID"
$clientId = "clientID"
$thumbprint = "certificateThumbprint"

# Authenticate to Microsoft Graph using the certificate
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbprint

# Number of days a device must be inactive before deletion (180 days in this case)
$dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

# Initialize an array to hold all devices
$AllDevices = @()

# Fetch devices from Microsoft Graph with pagination
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices"
do {
    Write-Host "Fetching devices from: $uri"
    $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method GET -Uri $uri
    if ($response -and $response.value) {
        $AllDevices += $response.value
        Write-Host "Fetched $($response.value.Count) devices"
    } else {
        Write-Host "No devices fetched or response is null"
    }
    $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'
} while ($uri -ne $null)

# Debugging: Output the total number of devices fetched
Write-Host "Total devices fetched: $($AllDevices.Count)"

# Filter devices that have not signed in for 180 days or more and are disabled
$DevicesToDelete = $AllDevices.value | Where-Object {
    ($_.approximateLastSignInDateTime -le $dt)
}

# Debugging: Output the number of devices identified for deletion
Write-Host "Devices identified for deletion: $($DevicesToDelete.Count)"

# Output devices for review (testing mode)
if ($DevicesToDelete.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Devices identified for deletion (not deleted in this run):"
    $DevicesToDelete | Select-Object displayName, id, approximateLastSignInDateTime
} else {
    Write-Host "No devices found that meet the criteria for deletion."
}

# Delete the devices that were inactive for 180 days or more
# foreach ($Device in $DevicesToDelete) {
#     Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method DELETE -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices/$($Device.id)"
#     Write-Host "Deleted device: $($Device.displayName)"
# }

#Write-Output "Device cleanup process completed."

The last part of the script is commented out as I do not want to delete anything during testing. Maybe the way I am going about this is totally wrong as well. I am happy for all the help!
Thanks!

Could you include what API permissions you granted in your app registration by adding Portal image?

Added picture from Azure

Could you confirm whether you are getting the response when you run same script locally?

I am able to fetch all devices correctly locally (with the pagination). However, it marks 0 devices for deletion, maybe the filter is not working correctly, or it does not fetch the attribute from Graph.
Still it does not fetch anything in the automation.

In my case, your script working correctly locally, Check this https://i.imgur.com/uXpmq4V.png

In my case it works partly yes, but I would have over a thousand stale devices which should be marked for deletion, and it also says it found 0 devices marked for deletion. It does fetch them though.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There are a few issues with your code and improvements you can make.

First, Host output (produced by Write-Host) isn't visible in the Automation Account Job output. The only outputs that the AA knows are Success, Error and Warning.

Second issue is here:
$DevicesToDelete = $AllDevices.value | Where-Object {

There is no .value in the objects of $AllDevices, those are already device type objects.

An improvement, you don't need to filter approximateLastSignInDateTime client side, Graph API knows how to filter by this property:

In essence you can do:
# `o` format is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ`, Graph accepts it no problem :)
$dt = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-180).ToString('o')
$uri = "v1.0/devices?`$filter=approximateLastSignInDateTime le $dt"


$AllDevices = @() and $AllDevices += $response.value is inefficient, should be avoided. You can simply assign the result of the loop expression to a variable, i.e.: $AllDevices = do { ..... $response.value }. See Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection for details.


In summary, your code can be:
# Authenticate to Microsoft Graph using the certificate
$connectMgGraphSplat = @{
    ClientId              = 'clientID'
    TenantId              = 'tenantID'
    CertificateThumbprint = 'certificateThumbprint'
    NoWelcome             = $true
}
Connect-MgGraph @connectMgGraphSplat

# Number of days a device must be inactive before deletion (180 days in this case)
$dt = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-180).ToString('o')

# Fetch devices from Microsoft Graph with pagination where
# `approximateLastSignInDateTime` is lower than or equal to `$dt`
$uri = "v1.0/devices?`$filter=approximateLastSignInDateTime le $dt"
$DevicesToDelete = do {
    $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri
    if ($response.value) {
        $response.value
    }
    $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'
} while ($uri)

# Debugging: Output the total number of devices TO DELETE fetched
# NOTE: `Write-Host` was removed here, same as below with `"Deleted device:...`
"Total devices to delete fetched: $($DevicesToDelete.Count)"

foreach ($Device in $DevicesToDelete) {
    Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method DELETE -Uri "v1.0/devices/$($Device.id)"
    "Deleted device: $($Device.displayName)"
}


Thanks, this works like a charm. Only thing is I cannot use the scope parameter in the Splat as Scopes are not needed when using CertificateThumbprint for authentication. The permissions are tied to the app registration itself, so I guess I could just remove the other API permissions just in case?

@Unbuckle glad it helped! yes you're right, -Scopes isnt needed in this case.
